# How to get wav file from melspectrogram, is there a librosa function available

Tags: python, wav, librosa

I have loaded a Audio File, extracted Mels feature using Librosa in python:

```
import librosa
file_path=st.folderloc+file_path
X,sr = librosa.load(file_path,sr=st.g_sr_global) # 22050, 44100 # , offset=0.05, ,duration=2
print('sample rate:' ,sr)
S = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=X, sr=sr, n_mels=128, fmax=2000)
```

Want to know is there a way to get the WAV file back if I only Supply  mels 
co eff, and I know the n_mels=128, sr=44100

Comment: Something like librosa.output to wav file , is what I am looking for when my source is melspectogram  2D array